# Angular2 Hiding element class member

Tags: html, angular, angular-material2

I'm trying to use *ngIf to show and hide an element based on a member of the class its built on. But I keep encountering the following error despite being able to use other data members to display titles, etc.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'hidden' of undefined
```

My html looks like

```
...
<md-list-item *ngFor="let navigation of flatNavList"
  (click)="onSelect(navigation)" *ngIf="navigation.hidden==false">
  {{navigation.title}}
</md-list-item>
...
```

with a navigation array in my *component.ts file defined as

```
...
flatNavList: Navigation[];
...
```

and the Navigation class looking like

```
export class Navigation {
    constructor(
        public name: string,
        public title: string,
        public icon: string,
        public location: string,
        public hidden: boolean,
        public roles: string[],
        public children: Navigation[]
    ) { }
}
```

If I remove the *ngIf everything renders fine. Why can I use navigation.title to display the name, yet I can't use navigation.hidden to toggle whether or not the element is displayed?

EDIT------------------------------

```
[hidden]="navigation.hidden"
```

But several articles say that this is bad practice in Angular 2

Comment: Try to use the elvis operator like `navigation?.hidden`

Comment: That causes it to compile, but it doesn't give me the functionality

Comment: What if you add `{{navigation?.hidden}}` inside `<md-list-item>` instead of `*ngIf="navigation.hidden==false"` to see what values it contains.  To me it looks like you have `null` elements in `flatNavList`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer It doesn't like the interpolation when using {{navigation.hidden}} or {{navigation?.hidden}}. There are no null elements in the flatNavList.

Comment: Hard to tell without being able to investigate it in a running example. Can you create a Plunker?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that navigation is undefined sometimes.
So first test for it and then check its hidden property:

```
*ngIf="navigation && !navigation.hidden"
```